# Migrate separate Perforce branches to a single Git repository

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I'm trying to migrate a project from Perforce to Git.

I have an unusual scenario (at least I haven't found anyone asking anything remotely similar), under which the Perforce projects look like this:

```
//depot/MAIN
----------------------------------------X--------------------
                                       / - OTHER merged
        -------------------------------
        //depot/OTHER
```

I'm trying to migrate MAIN to Git. MAIN started before OTHER, and still exists. OTHER was merged into MAIN at a certain point by performing a Perforce "move/rename" operation.

When I look in Perforce at the history of the files in MAIN that originally came from OTHER, I can see the *full history*, including the changes that happened before the move.

But when I migrated MAIN to Git (using git-p4 clone), the history of all the files that came from OTHER starts when the files where moved (at the X above).

So, the obvious question is: how can I migrate the *complete* history to Git, including the revisions that were done in OTHER?

Answer (score 0):

One option if there isn't anything better:

Export both to git separately, then use [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/esr/reposurgeon/) to combine them together - NB: I've not done this, but [reposurgeon](http://www.catb.org/esr/reposurgeon/reposurgeon.html) says it can combine/graft repos.

Comment: As far as I know there is no merge detection implemented in git-p4 at the moment. So what you propose will more likely be the best option available.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder, sounds like an interesting direction, I started reading about it and tried to run in but I even can't seem to get it to start, getting:
`File "/home/git-p4/reposurgeon-3.20/reposurgeon", line 182
 preserve={b'.git/config', b'.git/hooks'}, SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Any idea? Or perhaps I should post a new question about that problem?

Comment: @TalRaveh which version of python are you using? reposurgeon requires 2.7.2 or newer.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder we had Python 2.6.6 installed on that machine. I actually looked, and couldn't find a required Python version in the Reposurgeon site or docs. I will try to install 2.7.8 (latest) and see if it works now, thanks :)

Comment: @TalRaveh I looked at the source from the reposurgeon site, and it was in a comment at the top.

Comment: Also 2.7.9 is the current most recent python2 version.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder right... apparently upgrading the Python version on CentOS 6.4 is not straightforward... gonna take me a while (this is not my highest priority atm), but I will test it and let you know... thanks :)

Comment: @TalRaveh You can build your own version of python in your user area just for this work. Or you could do the conversion in a VM with a newer version of python.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Perforce Git Fusion, you can create a repo that maps both the 'main' and 'other' branch.

When you then clone this repo, it will contain both branches, with al of their Perforce history converted.

I can't tell you exactly how this will look, without looking at the integration history in detail.

More information about Git Fusion, including how to create repos, is available in the Git Fusion admin guide:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/git-fusion/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not interested in using Perforce Git Fusion. I want to get rid of Perforce altogether (we are going to use GitHub Enterprise as back end).